# How to do git add . with fugitive?

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

How do you do `git add .` in Fugitive for vim?

THe command `:Git add .` is not doing adding anything

Comment: I was just wondering why it doesn't work in the plugin...

Comment: Then use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Did you know there is a Stack Exchange Community for vim? [Check it out](http://vi.stackexchange.com/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why `Git add .` doesn't work, but you can use `--` to seperate `Git add` from the path, so `Git add -- .` does the job.

Answer (score 14):

I think you are looking for `:Gwrite`.

The video [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-working-with-the-git-index/) explains fugitive and what the command does very well.

Comment: `:Gstatus` explained in the linked video is really awesome!